# Two ways to calculate current density, both give different answers, which is correct?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm given a vector potential in cylindrical coordinates:
$$\vec A(s,\phi,z) = \frac{A_oa}{s}e^\frac{-s^2}{a^2} \hat \phi$$

If I calculate the current density by taking the laplacian of $\vec A$, I get one answer with 3 different terms.

If I calculate $\vec B$ by taking the curl of $\vec A$, and then calculate $\vec J$ by taking the curl of $\vec B$, I get a different answer with only one term. I know that they should give the same answer, right? Have I made a mistake in the math? The laplacian involves 2 differentiations with respect to $s$ requiring the product rule, but the curl has the $s$ term cancel before differentiation leading to no use of the product rule and only one term.

What am I missing?

Comment: s is radial distance from the center. a is some constant, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector identity you are attempting to use is
$$
\vec{\nabla}\times(\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{A})
= \vec{\nabla} (\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{A})
- \nabla^2\vec{A}\,,
$$
where the Laplacian is understood to be the Laplacian of each *Cartesian* component separately.

In this case, since
$$
\vec{A}=A_0\frac{a}{s}e^{-s^2/a^2}\hat{\phi}\,,
$$
where $s$ is the radial coordinate in cylindrical coordinates, and $\hat{\phi}$ is the unit vector along the azimuthal direction, we can quickly compute that
$$
\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{A} =0\,,
$$
since $A_\phi$ has no $\phi$-dependence.  Then, when we take the Laplacian of $\vec{A}$, it's understood that we have to take the Laplacian of each *Cartesian* component separately.  Therefore, we write
\begin{align}
\nabla^2\vec{A} &= \nabla^2\left(A_0\frac{a}{s}e^{-s^2/a^2}
\left(-\sin(\phi)\,\hat{x}+\cos(\phi)\,\hat{y}\right)\right)\\
&=
-\nabla^2\left(A_0\frac{a}{s}e^{-s^2/a^2}
\sin\phi\right)\hat{x}
+
\nabla^2\left(A_0\frac{a}{s}e^{-s^2/a^2}
\cos\phi\right)\hat{y}\,.
\end{align}
Without going through the calculations here (because I suspect this is where the primary error in the OP was, that you have to take the Laplacian of the Cartesian components), we get
$$
\nabla^2\vec{A} = 4A_0\frac{s}{a^3}e^{-s^2/a^2}\hat{\phi}\,.
$$
Similarly, computing the curl of the curl, we get
$$
\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{A}
= -4A_0\frac{s}{a^3}e^{-s^2/a^2}\hat{\phi}\,.
$$
The results then match.

Comment: Interesting. I checked the Griffiths derivation of the vector potential formula, and the chapter 1 "curl of a curl" explanation and you're right, it's all done in cylindrical coordinates. I'll be damned.